# Displaying from one to hasMany relation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display my Location name in View but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

**Location Model** -

```
public function orderz()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order', 'location', 'location_id');
}
}
```

**Order Model**

```
public function location()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Order');
}
```

**LocationsController.php -**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $locations = Location::find($id)->orderz()->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString());
    $orders = Order::all();
    $wallets = Wallet::all();
    //$orders = DB::table('orders')->where('location', '=', 'New York')->get();
    return view('location')
        ->with('locations', $locations)
        ->with('wallets', $wallets)
        ->with('orders', $orders);
}
```

I'm calling it like that:

```
@foreach ($locations as $location)
    @foreach($location->orders as $order)
        {{$order->location_id}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

When I remove from my code date filter It's works but I'm showing orders from all days.

```
        $locations = Location::find($id)->orders()->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString());
```

to look like that:

```
$locations = Location::find($id)->orders;
```

Comment: you named the relationship `orderz` but calling it as `orders`

Comment: Why you're calling ->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString()) ?

Comment: on your location model rename  the orderz function as `orders`

Comment: As well as the `z` typo, if this is a standard 1-to-many relation, I think you have your relations set up wrong.  Your Location model `orderz()` hasMany Orders; but your Order model `location()` ... belongsTo an Order? That should be Location, I think?

Comment: @apokryfos I renamed it but problem is not in them.

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI, because I want to receiving records only per today date.

Answer (score 0):

You may use eager loading :

```
//Controller
$locationWithOrderz = Location::with('orderz')->where('id', $id)->first();
$wallets = Wallet::all();

return view('location')
    ->with('location', $locationWithOrderz)
    ->with('wallets', $wallets);

//blade

@foreach($location->orderz as $order)
        {{$order->...}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I'm receiving this: "Undefined variable: orders (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\softuni\ticket-listing\resources\views\location.blade.php)"

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller code to something like this.

If you want to get location by id:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $locationWithOrderz = Location::with('orderz')->where('id', $id)->first();
    $orders = Order::all();
    $wallets = Wallet::all();

return view('location', compact('locationWithOrderz', 'wallets', 'orders'));
}
```

**Update**
You can't loop through $locations when you are retrieving single record. (Thank you @FouedMOUSSI)

```
foreach($locationWithOrderz->orderz as $order)
    {{$order->location_id}}
@endforeach
```

To get location by date:

```
public function index()    //Changed function name and argument
{
$locations = Location::with('orderz')->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())->get();
$orders = Order::all();
$wallets = Wallet::all();

return view('location', compact('locations', 'wallets', 'orders'));
}
```

Note: You'll need to match exact format of date being stored in created_at when using Carbon (without minutes and seconds) or you'll probably get nothing in $locations.

Here you can loop through locations:

```
@foreach ($locations as $location) 

    @foreach($location->orders as $order)
    {{$order->location_id}}
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: ->where('id', $id) must return one result

Comment: @Foued OP is looping in $locations in the blade.

Comment: AFAIK  The primary key (id) must be unique. so when you apply ->where('id', $id) filter , i'm quite sure you'll get only 1 row . right ?

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI That's true. I missed that. I'll update my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I tried with your code but it doesn't work also and with your code can't sum total prices of locations  - "{{$locations->sum('total')}}"

Comment: If you could please elaborate on what are the fields that you are trying to get locations for. For example, between two times, etc.

Comment: It doesn't showing any error but still not showing location name and can't sum them.  Can I make any relations through SQL ?

Comment: That's perhaps because there might no matching records for the "where" that you're querying. Maybe try this first `$locations = Location::with ('orderz') - >all();` Also please update your question to include the code where you're doing sum on the collection.

Comment: Here we go https://ibb.co/1sDpsmj I have to show Location: New York and to sum orders per location for date(). I can sum them but can't show location names.

Comment: @QumberRizvi when I remove this:  ->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString()); from my controller It works but not showing records only per same day. Now my Controller is like:  "$locations = Location::find($id)->orders" And if I add () after orders it doesn't works again.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that in your one to many relationship, second argument must be the the foreign key in your Order model. Eloquent will automatically determine the proper foreign key column on Order table. Now your relationship must be.

```
public function orderz()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order', 'foreign_key_in_order_model', 'primary_key_in_location_model');
}
```

Your final code should look like this.

```
 public function orderz()
 {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order', 'location_id', 'location');
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I modified my code to get my ids because they are my default primary keys but it's still don't work...

Answer (score 0):

I just called one more time my locations with different variable and now all is ok

```
$loc = Location::find($id);
    $locations = Location::find($id)->orders()->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::today()->toDateString());
```

To display my location name I'm using

```
{{$loc->location_id}}
```